# AngularJS: ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The ng repeat is not working for my angular code.

Here is the partial:

```
 <section class="artistpage">
      <ul class="artistlist">
        <li ng-model = "questions" ng-repeat="item in questions">
          <input type="checkbox" name = "q">{{item.ct}}
          </input>
          </li>
         </ul>
    </section>
```

Here is the Controller:

```
var testControllers = angular.module('testControllers', []);

testControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/cat.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.questions = data;
  });
}]);
```

The data:

```
 [ 
   {
     "info":{  
         "cid":1,
         "ct":"T1",
         "ctg":"math",
         "pcid":78
      }
   },
   {
      "info":{  
         "cid":2,
         "ct":"T2",
         "ctg":"math",
         "pcid":78
      }
   },
   {
      "info":{  
         "cid":3,
         "ct":"T3",
         "ctg":"Py",
         "pcid":2
      }
   }
]
```

I have not been able to figure out why this is not working. Help please!

Comment: Says syntax error in JSON. But I check it in JSON validator

Comment: Doesn't matter what validators says: Angular can't parse it and use it, so you need to fix this. However, you are not giving enough info to help you because posted code is working. Try to set up failing demo maybe.

Comment: There was a comment in the JSOn file. I removed it and it works fine...

Comment: You see. Take a look as @Bharat Bhushan answer, he has a good point about ngModel. Not sure why it's downvoted but it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you are not accessing the object info, you should access each element info and get the value

change your ng-repeat like this,

```
<li ng-model = "question" ng-repeat="item in questions">
           {{item.info.ct}}
</li>
```

Working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/bPS4BC1MkphnYJpVfbXB?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
     <section class="artistpage">
      <ul class="artistlist">
        <li ng-model = "question" ng-repeat="item in questions">
          <input type="checkbox" name = "q">{{item.ct}}
          </input>
          </li>
         </ul>
    </section>
--------------use this-----------

 <section class="artistpage">
      <ul class="artistlist">
        <li ng-model = "question" ng-repeat="item in questions">
          <input type="checkbox" name = "q">{{item.info.ct}}
          </input>
          </li>
         </ul>
    </section>
```

ng-model should not be the same. so use ng-model="question" instead of questions

[Here is plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4DR2QY5V6yBSiR1wT37u)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace `{{item.ct}}` with `{{item.info.ct}}` as you have object `info` inside your outer object. Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/1909/)

```
<section class="artistpage">
      <ul class="artistlist">
        <li ng-model = "questions" ng-repeat="item in questions">
          <input type="checkbox" name = "q"/>{{item.info.ct}}
          </li>
         </ul>
</section>
```